# Do I need to add my server.js into my webpack file?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I have a node server with es6 syntax, like import statements, which it cannot recognize. I am pretty sure I would have to add that to my webpack file, but unsure on how to do that and whether it is required. My node server file is called `server.js`

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/index.js',
    vendor: './src/vendor.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendor','vendor.js', Infinity)
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel',
      query: {
        presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
      }
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './'
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

To use the `import` keyword in Node you have to transpile it so it either has to be processed by webpack if you use it or at least transpiled with a tool like Babel. See this for more info:

- https://github.com/babel/babel-preset-env